# How to serialize GenericForeignKey in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that uses a generic foreign key using "content_type" field to store content type and "object_id" to store object ID. This model needs to be manipulated with a CRUD API and I am using DRF. I have a serializer for the model, but I hit a bit of a problem. If I just add content_type to the list of fields like this

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'state', 'content_type', 'object_id')
```

The serializer sets the JSON representation to the ID of the ContentType model instance. The users of the API don't know these IDs and I do not want to expose ContentType model with yet another API. The API users do know the type of object they want to link though, so they can send a content type name. So, I have defined the serializer like this

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    content_type = serializers.CharField(source="content_type.name")
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'state', 'content_type', 'object_id')
```

Serializing the model works just fine. If I use the generic relationship to link a User instance, I get something like `{'name': 'test', 'state': 'NY', 'content_type': 'user', 'object_id': 123}`. But when I submit a PUT or POST request with the JSON structure, DRF converts this to something like `{'name': 'test', 'state': 'NY', 'content_type': {'name': {'name': 'user'}}, 'object_id': 123}`. I could write something like

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ct_model = validated_data['content_type']['name']['name']
        validated_data['content_type'] = ContentType.objects.get(model=ct_model)
        return MyModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

But it seems arbitrary and fragile. What is the right way to handle this situation?

**Update #1:** For the moment, I have solved the problem by overriding to_internal_value() with this code

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    content_type = data.get('content_type', None)
    validated_data = super().to_internal_value(data)
    try:
        validated_data['content_type'] = ContentType.objects.get(model=content_type)
    except ContentType.DoesNotExist:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("invalid content type %s" % content_type)
    return validated_data
```

It seems like a kind of an ugly hack to have to do to display a related object.

Comment: Did you try solution from the docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships ?

Comment: The solution seems to be to define a custom related field class. I will look into that, but that seems convoluted.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, post it as an answer and not as update.

Comment: This is not an answer I am looking for. I came up with an ugly hack that seems to resolve the immediate issue I am having. It is fragile and not efficient. I am still looking for a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to go custom, providing your own field class with `to_representation` and `to_internal_value` methods to serialize such relations. It's not that complicated, give it a try.

Consider using uri notations `/api/resource/object_id` as your serialization format.

Converting content types to resource uris and back can be a bit challenging (if you have more than a few possible types) but I'm sure there must be some easy way to do it.

Comment: If I use URI as content types, I would have to 1. expose content types via the API (and deal with a crapload of permission and filtering problems, since django creates a content type for every model in the system) 2. Force the API users to make several requests to obtain a single piece of data.

Comment: I don't think your 1. is true and I don't see how you can avoid permissions and filtering anyway but if you 2. want your api nested and slow instead you still will most probably have to customize the aforementioned serializer methods.

Comment: If I use uris for a nested resource, it should be possible to use the uri to obtain the resource. In this case, you suggested using uris for content types and that means I need to have an API to access content types. And that leads to having to restrict access to it in some non-obvious ways, since django creates content types for absolutely everything and I don't want to expose inner structure of the application to the API user.

As for the second part, I am not making my API nested. But even if I did, I am not sure you are in any position to judge its performance.